# Fetch multiple entities in Spring Boot when condition matches else return null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have specific use case where the application should read the data from multiple tables using Spring JPA. When there's data in table record(s) should be read into the entity object else the null should be updated in the respective entity object.

I've created entities and JPA repositories for each table and able to pull the data with multiple calls from Service class but I'd like to combine all the `Repository.findByUserId()` into one call to avoid multiple selects to DB.

Tables:

```
USER_DATA
| USER_ID (primary key) | USER_NAME |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1   | Name 1   |
| 2   | Name 2   |
| 3   | Name 3   |
```

```
TABLET_DATA
| USER_ID (foreign key) | PRODUCT_NAME |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1   | SAMSUNG   |
| 3   | IPAD      |
```

```
LAPTOP_DATA
| USER_ID (foreign key) | PRODUCT_NAME |
| -------- | -------- |
| 2   | DELL   |
| 3   | MAC    |
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="USER_DATA")
public class UserData {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="TABLET_DATA")
public class TabletEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(table = "USER_DATA", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="LAPTOP_DATA")
public class LaptopEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(table = "USER_DATA", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;
}
```

Respositories:

```
@Repository
public interface TabletRepository<TabletEntity, Long> extends JpaRepository {
    TabletEntity findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface LaptopRepository<LaptopEntity, Long> extends JpaRepository {
    LaptopEntity findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

Service:

```
public class ServiceBean {
    private String tabletName;
    private String laptopName;
}
```

```
public class DataService {
    @Autowired
    TabletRepository tabletRepository;
    @Autowired
    LaptopRepository laptopRepository;

    public ServiceBean fetchData(String userId) {
        TabletEntity tabletDetails = tabletRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        LaptopEntity laptopDetails = LaptopRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        ServiceBean object = new ServiceBean();
        if(tabletDetails != null) {
                object.setTabletName(tabletDetails.getProductName());
        }
        if(laptopDetails != null) {
                object.setLaptopName(laptopDetails.getProductName());
        }

        return object;
    }
}
```

Here I'd like to make only one DB call instead of 2 and also even if the table signature is similar I cannot merge into 1. My requirement is to pull the data when available in the table else null be returned for respective field.

Comment: You can use SQL query with subquery to fetch data from multiple tables

Comment: @ElyorbekIbrokhimov - Just as an example I gave 3 tables in the problem description but in my application I have 25+ tables which needs to be checked before returning the response. I don't know whether Spring Boot can accept multiple sub queries under ````select````.